# Program slicing in python

Tags: python, program-slicing

I am looking for some functionality to do program slicing. For example lets say I have the following code

```
print("Starting")
x = 25
prod = x * 20
div = x / 5
```

When I want the slice of the program that is needed for `prod` then the slicer should output me

```
x = 25
prod = x * 20
```

When I want to output the part of the program that depends of the variable x then I should get the output

```
x = 25
prod = x * 20
div = x / 5
```

I was looking at the tool https://github.com/romanofski/programslice but it doesn't help much.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm not going to claim that no tool can do this or that I know of any but it's a steep uphill battle, especially with a dynamic language.

Comment: This sounds .... mathematically undecidable.  In a `"you could prove this impossible to do completely and in finite time using Turing completeness"` kind of way.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "some functionality"? Are you asking for a library or module recommendation?